# 'undefined' function when triggering a click of a link with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason this works in FF 11, Chrome, and even in IE but not in FF 3.6 or Safari 5.

Basically I'm triggering the click of a link with:

```
var $currentItem = $('#' + currentId);
var modalSeriesList = $('.js-modal-series');
var index = modalSeriesList.index($currentItem);
var $nextItem = modalSeriesList[index + 1];

var nextClick = function() {
    $(document).off('keydown.general');
    $nextItem.click();
}

$(document).off('keydown.general');

if ($nextItem) {
    $nextButton.click(nextClick);
}​
```

But when I click on the link in FF 3.6 or Safari 5 I get the following error:

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$nextItem.click()')`

Is there any particular "gotcha" that I don't know about here using the following method?

Comment: It's just looks like you got outside of the array index.

Comment: should nextClick be nextClick()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) so `$nextItem` is a `jQuery` collection:

```
var $nextItem = modalSeriesList.eq(index + 1);

// ...

$nextItem.click()
```

Using `[...]` retrieves the DOM Object, which doesn't have a `.click()` method.

Comment: Wow dude. You NAILED it. Thanks!!! I should have known this though! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Had exactly the same problem as @bob_cobb myself. Weird thing is that only WebKit was tripping up with the calculated 'index' variable - Firefox worked fine...

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
if( typeof $nextItem == 'undefined' ){
    $nextButton.trigger('click');
}
```

instead of

```
if ($nextItem) {
    $nextButton.click(nextClick);
}​
```

Comment: I tried this and I get the same error. This is the weirdest thing. $nextItem definitely exists and it's a valid link, which makes sense since this works in other browsers...

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in jquery again like that : var $nextItem = $(modalSeriesList[index + 1]);  I think only accessing the index returns a plain dom element.

Answer (score 0):

if you turn condition of if statement into

```
if(typeof $nextItem == 'undefined' )
```

it works. As Porco said probably $nextItem does not exist....